# Installing PHP YAML Extension with XAMPP on Windows

Tags: php, windows, apache, xampp, yaml

Hey folks I am currently doing some work on PhP that requires me to parse a YAML file by using the `yaml_parse_file()` function. I am still new to the language and all so when I tried using that function on my unmodified XAMPP server on Windows I got the error 'function not found'. After some research I found out that you are actually supposed to install extensions on your php installation to be able to use that function. http://php.net/manual/en/yaml.setup.php this link details the installation process and I have read through it however I am confused in regards to the installation procedure. The above link states that there is not a DLL package available for download however a comment direct to this link http://pecl.php.net/package/yaml where you can clearly see a DLL Package for YAML Parser. My question is if you could please walk me through how to go about this installation procedure on a Windows Machine using XAMPP.

Edit: https://code.google.com/p/php-yaml/wiki/InstallingWithPecl this link might offer you more insight on this topic although I fail to understand how it all works :(

Edit2: I have tried to download the DLL given on the above link and add it to my php/ext folder and add an entry in php.ini `extension=php_yaml.dll` but when I try to test if my extension has been loaded by the following script, I get an error.

```
<?php
if (extension_loaded(yaml))
  echo "yaml loaded :)";
else
  echo "something is wrong :(";
?>
```

Comment: you got any solution ?

Comment: Hey, I don't have a solution yet. Still looking for answers.

Comment: Check my solution on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27355513/installing-yaml-in-xampp-windows/27372853#27372853 and let me know if you need any help

Comment: Umm nope. Sorry didn't work. It asks for an additional yaml.dll file that does not exist. :(

Answer (score 24, accepted):

With a bit of help from the readers I seem to have narrowed down the steps to accomplish this.

1. [Download the latest YAML DLL Package](http://pecl.php.net/package/yaml)
2. Unzip the files
3. Move the `php_yaml.dll` file to `xampp/php/ext` folder
4. Open your `php.ini` in `xampp/php` and add the line `extension=php_yaml.dll`, save and exit
5. Now move the `yaml.dll` file from the zip folder contents and move it to the `xampp/apache/bin` folder
6. Close and restart your XAMPP Servers
7. Load a php script `echo phpinfo();`
8. Search the string `yaml` on the page. If it says Enabled then your YAML Extension is working.

Comment: Step 5 is probably the missing piece for a lot of people. It's not exactly explained in the readme included in the PECL download.

Comment: Step 5 works for Apache, but if you want this to also work for PHP CLI then you need to assure that the directory is in your PATH. I placed the file in another directory, that was in my PATH, and it worked for both Apache and PHP CLI.

Comment: PHP 7.1 DLL -> https://github.com/Alvine-IO/php7-windows/tree/master/7.1.5/x64/ts

Comment: Step 5 is no longer necessary. Used PHP 7.3 with XAMPP Control Panel v3.2.4.

Comment: No luck for me. PHP 7.3.11 and XAMPP 3.2.4. DLL is in xampp/php/ext and entry is added to php.ini. Apache crashes on startup.

Comment: Where do I get `yaml.dll`? When I download the latest yaml dll, it contains `php_yaml.dll` only.

Comment: Step 5 is not required anymore. I am using php 7.4

Comment: If you are not sure if you need the thread safe or non thread safe version on the yaml download, use phpinfo(), look for "Thread Safety," if "enabled" you need the thread safe version otherwise the non thread safe version.

Answer (score 4):

As of 2018.04.17, Windows 10, Step 5 above is nonsensical: there is no yaml.dll available.

My solution was to copy the php.ini file from the php folder into the location Apache was looking into for its use of php.
phpinfo() told me that was c:\windows (which you need admin rights to write into)

Earlier I had just copied php_yaml.dll into the apache dll folder. I have left it there maybe it's part of the solution too.

PS. Thanks &^%* admins for deleting my earlier call for help. THAT didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Originally answered by @shadoweye14. As of php 7.4. Here is the updated answer.

1. [Download the latest YAML DLL Package](http://pecl.php.net/package/yaml/2.2.2/windows)
2. Unzip the files
3. Move the php_yaml.dll file to xampp/php/ext folder
4. Open your php.ini in xampp/php and add the line extension=php_yaml.dll, save and exit
5. Close and restart your XAMPP Servers
6. Load a php script echo phpinfo();
7. Search the string yaml on the page. If it says Enabled then your YAML Extension is working.