# Installing Yaml in xampp windows

Tags: php, xampp, yaml

I am trying to install [YAML](http://www.yaml.org/) in **`XAMPP windows 64 bit`**

1. Downloaded the .dll file from http://pecl.php.net/package/yaml/1.1.1/windows
2. enabled the extension in php ini as follows

   extension=php_yaml.dll
3. Restarted the Apache
4. Getting the following error php startup unable to load dynamic library

> "\xampp\php\ext\php_yaml.dll"

Is this is the right way or I am missing any thing ? Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of research, I finally found a solution

1. Go to https://github.com/LegendOfMCPE/LoM-CMS/wiki/How-to-Install-LibYAML
2. See the below link **For windows**
   http://search.4shared.com/postDownload/ComqwjFvce/php_yaml-102-dev-54-vc9-x86.html
3. Download that zip file
4. Unzip it and put yaml.dll inside xampp folder
5. php_yaml.dll inside xampp/php/ext/ folder
6. add extension=php_yaml.dll in php.ini and Restart apache. If possible restart the system
7. Execute the following lines in a php file to check the extension loaded or not

   > if (extension_loaded(yaml))      echo "yaml loaded :)";    else
   > echo "something is wrong :(";

Comment: your second link is broken.

Comment: The problem is that yaml extension is sucessfully loaded in web mode, but its missing in cli.

Answer (score 0):

Although I checked all the steps, there was point where I missed: Adding PHP to PATH. Because in php.ini `extension_dir` is given as a relative path as example `extension_dir=ext`.

In order to operating system to find that path, the root path of PHP must be given to the operating system. In Windows it is via `Right click to This PC -> Features -> Advanced System Settings -> Enviroment Variables`