# How to install YAML extension to PHP 7.4?

Tags: php, yaml, php-extension

I'm trying to install YAML extension to PHP 7.4.4 on Windows.

Steps I've taken:

- Downloaded the latest DLL package from https://pecl.php.net/package/yaml (currently 2.1.1) for 7.4 Non Thread Safe (NTS) x64.
- Copied `php_yaml.dll` to the extension folder `C:/my_path/bin/php/php-7.4.4-Win32-vc15-x64/ext`
- Added `extension=yaml` to php.ini.
- At this point, all [tutorials](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27379895/628637) I've found instruct to copy `yaml.dll` to a bin folder, but there is no such file in the current YAML package.

When I run PHP now, it gives me the following error:

> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'yaml' (tried: C:/my_path/bin/php/php-7.4.4-Win32-vc15-x64/ext\yaml (The specified module could not be found.), C:/my_path/bin/php/php-7.4.4-Win32-vc15-x64/ext\php_yaml.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0

What else do I need to do to get YAML to work in PHP?

Comment: Please share more details, like the configuraiton of your extension directory. Do the paths listed in the error match your PHP installation paths?

Comment: @NicoHaase `C:/my_path/bin/php/php-7.4.4-Win32-vc15-x64` is my PHP installation path. The file `./ext/php_yaml.dll` exists and is the lastest DLL from yaml package. The folder `./ext/yaml` doesn't exists. Do you need any more info?

Comment: It should be `extension=yaml.dll` and you should rename the file to `yaml.dll` too.

Comment: @arkascha That gives the following error: `Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'yaml.dll' (tried: C:/my_path/bin/php/php-7.4.4-Win32-vc15-x64/ext\yaml.dll (The specified module could not be found.), C:/my_path/bin/php/php-7.4.4-Win32-vc15-x64/ext\php_yaml.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0`

Comment: OK, so without the ".dll" file name extension. Compare it to other extensions getting loaded.

Comment: @arkascha Yes, all other extensions are loaded in the same way as in the question. Others are working, yaml is not working.

Comment: Then maybe that library is the wrong version. Compiler incompatibility is a typical cause, though one usually gets a specific hint in that case...