# Missing dll on yaml for PHP download

Tags: php, xampp, yaml

I try to install yaml extension for php in xampp. So I download the last version here : https://pecl.php.net/package/yaml

All tutorials I found, talk about a dll file, but there isn't any dll file, how can I install yaml for php in xampp ?

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing PHP YAML Extension with XAMPP on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27122701/installing-php-yaml-extension-with-xampp-on-windows)

Comment: No it's no answer my question....